# Is there a way to sort by per-volume or per-weight price on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I'm looking to compare prices on Amazon to some local retailers for protein supplement powder.  However, ideally an answer would work for any product that is sold in bulk by volume or weight.

There are almost 1500 products in the [protein supplement category](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?rh=n%3A3760901%2Ck%3Awhey+protein%2Cn%3A%213760931%2Cn%3A3764441%2Cn%3A3773091&bbn=3764441&keywords=whey+protein&ie=UTF8&qid=1322630562&rnid=3764441#/ref=sr_hi_4?rh=n%3A3760901%2Cn%3A%213760931%2Cn%3A3764441%2Cn%3A3773091%2Cp_n_feature_six_browse-bin%3A2255090011&bbn=3773091&ie=UTF8&qid=1322630583) on Amazon, many of which are different sizes/flavors of the same stuff from the same manufacturers.  Since I use the stuff regularly, and lack any brand preference, I mostly just want to see a listing sorted by price per pound.

Is there a way to do that, either on Amazon.com or via some third-party tool or site that knows how to query their product database?

Comment: There is no way I know to do this on Amazon or a third party.
You could write some javascript to sort it out. From what I can see they use javascript to sort it.                                                                            You can see via their page source how they do it.

Answer (score 4):

[BangYourBuck](https://bangyourbuck.com) does exactly this. You can choose your unit of choice (pounds, grams, etc.). Note that the links provided do have affiliate links.

[image: BangYourBuck screenshot]

Comment: I just tried this site and thought it was great until I saw the usual randomly distributed brands and items that plagues Amazon's search engine. For example, I searched for `9V Energizer Alkaline Batteries`––[BangYourBuck - 9v energizer alkaline batteries by the Count - US - Table View](https://bangyourbuck.com/search/9v%20energizer%20alkaline%20batteries/Count/US/table)––and the top results were for mixed brands of AAA batteries. I then did a page search for `9V` and most of the results were for random brands and only a couple were for Energizer brand.

Comment: Just tried BYB for the first time ever and it found a sku with a lower unit cost than I could find! It even stacked further with an amazon spend $50 get 20% off (lucky timing) to be substantially lower than my best attempt.

Comment: I was searching for Printing Paper, and using the "Count" parameter it gave mixed results. Amazon seems to provide a "price/100 Sheets" value for most of these items. Sometimes they're also provided as "price/stück" (sic, German) or missing altogether.

Also including the shipping costs or excluding non-Prime items would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the Amazon web site it's not possible but you could create your own front end by using the [Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html). It requires the following knowledge and skills:

> - XML (For an overview, see [W3 Schools XML Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp).)
> - Basic understanding of web services (For an overview, see [W3 Schools Web Services
>     Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp).)